# Rectifier to Step Down Buck Regulator

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck, rectifier, texas-instruments

I'm trying to simulate an AC to DC voltage regulator. I'm trying to go from 115 Vrms to 5 V DC at 1 amp max, though 0.5 amps nominally. I initially thought of using the LM317 at first, but after discussion, it seems that it would give off too much heat. Thus, I decided to go with a different IC, the TI LM2596 as shown in my circuit below. From what I've researched, it should use up less current than the LM317, so I thought it would be a good replacement without fear of overheating.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff2CID.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transformer rectifies the voltage to a DC voltage of 13.63 volts held by C1, and that input goes into the IC which outputs 5 volts at the output. I never worked with buck converters before so I followed the recommended circuit layout, but is this the correct configuration when working with unfiltered DC voltage from a rectifier? Should there be some circuit protection at VIN to protect the IC, or is it fine as it is? I'm trying to get this working in simulation, but compared with working with the linear LM317, the SPICE model is really slow and sluggish, so it's hard to get accurate results about the circuit.

EDIT: After some thoughtful discussion, I had to change my design to fit some new requirements. See the new schematic. I used one single transformer to rectify the secondary to two 13 V, and I use two IC configurations to output a positive and negative voltage with a start-up delay. Regarding the new edition, does it still hold true, or should some parameters change?

Comment: If you end up making this outside of a simulation, be aware that switching regulators can be *very picky* about how they're physically arranged on the PCB. Be sure to read section 10 of the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf).

Comment: @Hearth Thanks. I saw another post regarding someone's layout when they tried to use the IC. If switching regulators are picky about their layout, wouldn't it be simpler to use a linear regulator?

Comment: Yes, linear regulators are simpler. But linear regulators are also really inefficient. And heatsinks are expensive. Really, just be aware of *why* they're so particular about the layout and you should have a good understanding of how to lay it out. Besides, they almost always provide a sample layout, and you can just use that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine, but I think you should have a much bigger mains filter capacitor (maybe 4,700uF or so). Also watch the ripple current rating on the capacitor. The one you have will have something like 6V ripple across it which is too much.

Also watch that the DC resistance is not too high on the 20uH choke, as it's outside the feedback loop and will degrade the regulation.

I don't think you need to do anything special to protect the input, the transformer will saturate. The basic LM2576 is okay with up to 45V in.

Naturally switching regulators tend to take more computing horsepower to simulate than linear regulators. You can try LTspice and TI's web bench.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll take those points into consideration, but if you don't mind me asking, and this may be kind of opposite of my main question, but is there any reason as to use a DC-DC switching regulator than a linear regulator like the LM317? I'm only sourcing 0.5 A at best, and the LM317 seems really simple. I was worried about the IC overheating and having to replace it constantly so that's why I'm looking into the LM2576. Which resistance are you talking about with the 20 uH choke? Also, I'm using LTspice, and it's rather slow with TI's SPICE model.

Comment: The main reason is to reduce the power consumption. At 0.5A from 13.5V you'd be dissipating more than 4W in a linear regulator, which requires a significant heatsink (and wastes energy). As to the inductor, consider [this](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/bourns-inc/SRR1280-221K/SRR1280-221KLTR-ND/1970008) one which has a saturation current and current rating that is adequate. The DCR is 0.4 ohms so at 0.5A the output voltage will drop by 200mV from the unloaded output voltage just from the series resistance.

Comment: Thanks again. Regarding simulation speed, is there anything that I can do to speed it up? I'd hate to make a board and have it go to waste because my sim was wrong.

Comment: Web bench takes maybe 20-30 seconds to simulate startup. They also suggest a much higher value inductor [680uH](https://www.we-online.de/katalog/datasheet/74437529203681.pdf) for 0.5A out so you might want to check the calculations. I didn't try LTspice. Faster computer helps, of course.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. Using TI's Webbench designer, what values are you inputting to get those values? I'm not getting the high value inductor that you are suggesting. Also, that pair of L2 and C3 are the optional output ripple filter.

Comment: 0.5A out and 14V in.  L2 has the effect I mentioned.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106436/discussion-between-user101402-and-spehro-pefhany).